# Toggle 2 classes on each element of v-for based on conditions

Tags: javascript, api, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

I'm trying to list a list of chats between 2 users with vue 2.
in my style, i have 2 classes 'left' and 'right' helping to display if the chat belongs to the first or the last user.

here is my loop

```
 <div class="row chats-container">
    <div class="row chat-message clearfix" 
        v-for="chat in chats">
        <img src="./../../assets/userDefault.png" alt="">
        <span>{{chat.chat}}</span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the condition i want to use : `'v-if="auth.id === chat.sender.id"'`

I would like to toggle between two classes : `left` and `right`

Need some helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use property binding on the `class` attribute like `:class` and then you can use the properties and methods of your `vue-component`.

```
<div class="row chats-container">
   <div 
       v-for="chat in chats"
       :class='{"row": true, "chat-message": true, "clearfix": true, "left": auth.id !== chat.sender.id, "right": auth.id === chat.sender.id}'
   >
     <img src="./../../assets/userDefault.png" alt="">
     <span>{{chat.chat}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

If the length of that annoys you (it annoys me), you can setup a method:

```
methods: {
  textMessageStyle (chat) {
    return {
      "row": true,
      "chat-message": true, 
      "clearfix": true,
      "left": auth.id !== chat.sender.id, 
      "right": auth.id === chat.sender.id
    }
  }
}
```

and then:

```
<div class="row chats-container">
   <div 
       v-for="chat in chats"
       :class="textMessageStyle(chat)" 
   >
     <img src="./../../assets/userDefault.png" alt="">
     <span>{{chat.chat}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```